# matplotlib: looping though data to produce multiple plots

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib

I'm trying to loop through some data and this is my code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=120)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
e_key_list = [0.14, 0.23, 0.41, 0.77, 1.26,  1.3, 1.7, 2.2, 3.0, 4.1, 5.8]
e_width_ls = [0.09, 0.18, 0.36, 0.49, 66.74, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 1.1, 1.7, 7.0]

for d in range(7):
    for i in range(len(tme[0])):
        bin_data = []
        if i == 4:
            continue
        #print i
        for j in range(len(e_eng[i+1])):
            if 4.2 <= x[j] <= 5 and int(day[0])+d == int(day[j]):
                bin_data.append(e_eng[i+1][j] - e_bc[i+1][j])

        bin_data = np.array(bin_data)
        ax.bar(e_key_list[i], np.mean(bin_data), color ='g', width = e_width_ls[i], edgecolor = 'k', align ='edge')
    plt.show()
```

I want each iteration of d (which is meant to represent day) to produce a plot, but I only get a plot for d = 0. On the other hand, if plt.show() isn't included, all the 7 plots I want to create are displayed on the same histogram. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to have one new figure (that is, a new window) for every day, or multiple plots side-by-side in the same figure?

Comment: I was thinking of just plotting a new figure for every day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you want to have 7 figures, each with one barplot. To create a figure, you use `plt.figure`. However, instead of creating only one figure, you want 7 figures. Hence put the figure creation into the loop.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

e_key_list = [0.14, 0.23, 0.41, 0.77, 1.26,  1.3, 1.7, 2.2, 3.0, 4.1, 5.8]
e_width_ls = [0.09, 0.18, 0.36, 0.49, 66.74, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 1.1, 1.7, 7.0]

for d in range(7):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=120)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    for i in range(5):
        bin_data = []
        if i == 4:
            continue
        #print i
        for j in range(5):
            bin_data.append(j)

        bin_data = np.array(bin_data)
        ax.bar(e_key_list[i], np.mean(bin_data), color ='g', width = e_width_ls[i], edgecolor = 'k', align ='edge')
plt.show()
```

If you put `plt.show()` outside the loop as above all 7 figures will be shown at once.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't believe I missed it! It's been a long and frustrating day... Thanks again!